# How to select distinct value from multiple tables given a column filter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have this table

Products

| Id | ProductName | ProductCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alexa | P0001 |
| 2 | Alexa | P0002 |
| 3 | Alexa 2 | P0003 |
| 4 | Aquarium | P0004 |
| 5 | Aquarium X | P0004 |
| 6 | Bathtub | P0005 |

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetFilter]
    @filter nvarchar(max),
    @search nvarchar(max),
    @rows int = 10
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return TABLE([id] INT, [value] NVARCHAR(50));

    IF (@filter = 'ProductCode')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @return([value], [id])
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@rows) [Code] AS ProductCode, ProductId Id
        FROM [dbo].[Products]
        WHERE [Code] LIKE CONCAT(@search, '%')
        ORDER BY [Code];
    END
    IF (@filter = 'ProductName')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @return([value], [id])
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@rows)[Name] AS ProductName, ProductId Id
        FROM [dbo].[Products]
        WHERE [Name] LIKE CONCAT(@search, '%')
        ORDER BY [Name];
    END

    SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@rows) [id], [value] 
    FROM @return
    ORDER BY [value]
END
```

**Scenario 1:**

```
declare @filter nvarchar(max) = 'ProductName'
declare @search nvarchar(max) = 'A'
declare @rows int = 10    

exec [dbo].[usp_GetFilter] filter, @search, @rows
```

Expected Result: Returns distinct ProductName along with Id

| Id | ProductName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alexa |
| 3 | Alexa 2 |
| 4 | Aquarium |
| 5 | Aquarium X |

Actual result:

Returns all product name starting with 'A' distinct not working

**Scenario 2:**

```
declare @filter nvarchar(max) = 'ProductCode'
declare @search nvarchar(max) = 'P000'
declare @rows int = 10    

exec [dbo].[usp_GetFilter] filter, @search, @rows
```

Expected Result: Returns distinct Product Code along with Id

| Id | ProductCode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | P0001 |
| 2 | P0002 |
| 3 | P0003 |
| 4 | P0004 |
| 6 | P0005 |

Actual result:

Returns all product Code starting with 'P000' distinct not working

Comment: If all of your ProductId values are distinct, you will get all rows from the table in the results if you include that column in the SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: `@Filter` can never simultaneously be `ProductCode` and `ProductName` so why two branches populating a table variable? Why not just the two branches directly returning their search results?

Comment: You are getting proper values based off your query. DIstinct ProductCode.  If you want only the first 4 digits you would have to do DISTINCT LEFT(ProductCode, 4)  (or something similar.  But I do not see how this would be a good idea

Comment: instead of distinct you should select [Name], min([ProductId]) and group by Name, respectivly code in scenario 2

Comment: You will struggle to use a stored procedure that produces a resultset that varies by datatype. Presumably ProductID is the primary key (or at least unique) for the Product table, therefore DISTINCT has no logical effect. Doing that twice for each execution doesn't make much sense either. Don't depend on the database engine to ignore logic errors in order to optimize your code. Perhaps you look for a "first per group" if neither code nor name are unique?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning good point il prolly remove the return table and stick to separate selects

Comment: What is the point of the table variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check The Below Code:

Use `MIN` function

```
DECLARE
@filter nvarchar(max) = 'ProductCode',
@search nvarchar(max)='P000',
@rows int = 10

BEGIN
DECLARE @return TABLE([id] INT, [value] NVARCHAR(50));

IF (@filter = 'ProductCode')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @return([value], [id])
    SELECT TOP (@rows) [Code] AS ProductCode,  MIN( Id)
    FROM @Products
    WHERE [Code] LIKE CONCAT(@search, '%')
     GROUP BY [Code]
    ORDER BY [Code];
END
IF (@filter = 'ProductName')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @return([value], [id])
    SELECT TOP (@rows)[Name] AS ProductName, MIN( Id)
    FROM @Products
    WHERE [Name] LIKE CONCAT(@search, '%')
    GROUP BY [Name]
    ORDER BY [Name];
END

SELECT TOP (@rows) [id], [value] 
FROM @return
ORDER BY [id],[value]
END
```

Comment: trying this solution

Comment: This works. Just change the @Products to [dbo].[Products]